# Trying to create an interactive plot (newbie here)

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, interactive

I'm new at Mathematica so please bear with me. I am trying to create an interactive plot that will end up looking like this:
[image]
I want to input values for certain variables and then plot a curve.
This is what I have now.

```
     Manipulate[
     Plot[
      y = -((P*x^2)/(6*R*S)) (3*a - x),
      {x, 0, 10}],
     {P, 0, 10},
     {R, 0, 10},
     {S, 0, 10},
     {a, 0, 10}
     ]
```

Instead of slider bars, I want to have input boxes.

I have a few other issues. I don't know how to program a square. I believe this should be done piecewise, but I'm not sure how to do it on the same plot as my curve. Also, I'd like it so that the y-intercept auto manipulates so that the curve always touches the corner of the square. This might be a tad harder because I also want to add

```
    y = -((P*x^2)/(6*R*S)) (3*a - x)cos[[Theta]]
```

Is that even possible?

Thanks for the help.

edit: working off of @MarcoB 's advice, I got this now.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Graphics[{Rectangle[{1, 2}, {2, 4}]}],
  Plot[
   -(Px^2/6) (3 - x),
   {x, 0, 1}],
  {P, 2, 10}
   ]
 ]
```

edit 2: Working off of @MarcoB 's next comment, I managed to get a plot looking like this: [image]

My code is:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Graphics[{Rectangle[{1, 2}, {2, 3}]}],
  Plot[
   -(Px^2/6) (3 - x),
   {x, -2, 10},
   PlotStyle -> green],
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-2, 10}},
  Axes -> True
   ],
 {P, -10, 10}
 ]
```

Comment: Generally speaking, get the plot working with some fixed values first, then implement the manipulate functionality. More specifically, 1. Remove the `y =` in your plotting expression; 2. look up `Rectangle`, `Graphics`, and `Show`, in a combination as `Show[Graphics[{Rectange[yourspecs]}], Plot[plottingArguments]]`; 3. See [`InputField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputField.html) as a control type for Manipulate.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm getting this error message "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[...]

From reading the help menu, it would appear as though this is because my equation isn't a "graphics expression". How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the exact code you tried?

Comment: It doesn't seem to show up well in the comment. I'll add it to my original post.

Comment: The `{P, 2, 10}` fragment should be inside `Manipulate`, but outside `Show`, so `... {x, 0, 1}]], {P, 2, 10}]`

Comment: usually the `x` goes on the horizontal axis and the `y` on the vertical axis. Any reason you show them in the opposite order?

Comment: @Nasser I'm think I have x on the horizontal axis. Is it not that way?

Comment: I am looking at the screen shot you have above, but I see `y` on the horizontal axis, not `x`. may be the screen shot was rotated when pasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may start with this, add whatever you need and then remove the unnecessary manipulation parameters:

```
Manipulate[Show[{


 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, 
     Rectangle[{1 + a, c + b}, {2 + a, 4 + b}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-3, 0}}, Axes -> True, 
    AxesOrigin -> {1 + a, c}],

   Plot[{-(P*x^2/6) (3 - x), -k*x}, {x, 0, 1}, Axes -> True]
   }],

 {P, 2, 10}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -5, 1}, {c, 1, 5}, {k, 0, 3}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Let me try to understand it now :)